# Set default reviewers for merge request in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, review, merge-request

How I can set default reviewers in GitLab Premium?

In `Settings → General` I have only `Merge request (MR) approvals`, not reviewers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such setting in the UI. If you think it would be useful to others, please [file a feature request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/new?issuable_template=Feature%20Proposal%20-%20lean).

As a workaround, you could use the [Merge requests API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html) to set reviewers when [creating the MR](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr) or by [updating it after creation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#update-mr).

How you want to achieve the desired result depends on your workflow.

For example, you could have something [subscribe to the project webhook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhook_events.html#merge-request-events) which triggers a script that does the API call whenever it sees an `open` MR event.

Another option, if you run pipelines on MRs, you can have a job run a script which could set reviewers if none are already set via the API.

Yet another option would be to have a specified reviewer set when a merge request is created through the `/assign_reviewer @user` [quick action](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/quick_actions.html#issues-merge-requests-and-epics) by adding it to the default and all MR template files.

Comment: I've raised the feature request here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/413765

Answer (score 22):

You can use "**Default description template for merge requests**" either via `Settings->Merge Requests` or via file in `.gitlab/merge_request_templates` to do it via a workaround. [(Doc)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html)

In the template you can use the chat code

```
/assign_reviewer @user1 @user2 @user3
```

to automatically assign user1, user2 and user3 as reviewers when creating a new MR.

Comment: this is correct answer!

Comment: accidentally pressed on downvote; please edit this ticket and save it and ping me and I will press on upvote instead;

Answer (score 4):

Might be a useful workaround as this does not add you as a reviewer. (especially for gitlab free/CE 14.8+, as multiple reviewers are only available for Premium)

You could add a *Reviewers* section to your default MR template. Then persons will be notified with a Todo for the MR upon creation.

This should be in your default branch.

`.gitlab/merge_request_templates/default.md`

```
## What this MR does / why we need it 
- description
- proof of work


## Reviewers

- [ ] Reviewed by @gitlabUser1
- [ ] Reviewed by @gitlabUser2
- [ ] Reviewed by @gitlabUser3
- [ ] Reviewed by @gitlabUser4
- [ ] Reviewed by @gitlabUser5

Thanks for your MR, you're awesome! :+1:
```

The user can then check the checkbox upon review which will change the MR history too.

Comment: This is the perfect solution for those without Premium license. Or even with one, this is still a good way to visual it.

Answer (score -5):

Could you please try below

In Settings-->General-Merge Request Approvals.
[image]

Click on Add approval Rule.

[image]

Add Rule name as "Default", Approvals required, desired branch and add members under approvers.

These approvers would be your default reviewers for any Merge request.

Comment: That is not what this does.  This would simply mean that 1 approval would be required from someone on your list.  This does not pre-fill the reviewers on a new MR.